# php script to execute python script to write some files

Tags: php, python, linux, apache, ubuntu-10.04

I have a php script that calls a python script which in turn is in charge of writing some files to disk.

If I execute the php script by entering its url in the web browser it can perform several filesystem related tasks:

- it's able to create a dir
- it's able to chmod the dir

but it's not able to execute the python script which would create and write other files.

The strange thing is that if I run the python script manually as `www-data`:

```
user@host $ sudo su www-data
passwd for sudo:
$ whoami
www-data
$ python my_script.py
```

It works like a charm.

I'm assuming the user when I run the script through the browser is `www-data`. So why is the result in the console any different?

---

### SOLVED:

Python script starts off by importing some modules from my repository, which are appended to the path via `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` on login consoles. These modules were not available from the browser to the user `www-data`. So adding this to the python script solved it:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path_to_my_modules')
```

solved it.

I apologize for the question. It didn't bring all the necessary information for users to lead to a solution. I guess the problem was so broad that it was difficult for me to start thinking of where its root was.

I lacked a good debugging technique to see what the error was. I commented out all the python script and begun with a simple `print 'here'`. Uncommenting lines one by one showed me the place where it just didn't print anything anymore (the error was obvious then).

Comment: it's not clear from your info, if the .py script is invoked  from apache or not, can you find any errors in apache log related to script?  if you find no errors, try to add some basic commands (echo test to webpage) inside .py script to check if it even executed or not.

Comment: Inside the php script there's a line `exec($cmd, $output, $status);` The command is the python script. I can echo the command to the browser, copy paste it into the console where I'm www-data, and it runs. Yet, in the browser I get exit status 1

Comment: I meant sample command inside .py script, not in php.  status 1 - usually means - some error exception.

Comment: Can you post the relevant PHP code?

Comment: Sorry, I've been restless troubleshooting more urgent problems in the office, I'll come back to this later or tomorrow. Tankyou both for you help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't assume that the user is www-data. You should get the output from `whoami` running from the PHP script to see if it is `www-data`. Also, you need to make sure your script has `+x` or execute permissions for the user.

You should [read about execute permissions](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/).

You need to use `chown` on your PHP script to change the ownership to the `www-data` user:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data yourscript.php
```

Then you need to give the user execute permissions:

```
sudo chmod u+x yourscript.php
```

Comment: I did exec whoami from the browser, I confirm that the user is www-data. Anyway, my question is more about the difference between console and browser results

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'as root like you were in the console'? I thought I was www-data in the console. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcosModenesi My mistake. You were not actually running as root. You used `su` which means you switched to running as the `www-data` user. But, because you authenticated with `sudo` your terminal will allow you to do super user operations for a while without asking you to re-authenticate.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll wait for a while and see if I loose capabilities to execute that python script

Comment: So, those permissions didn't help? You might want to reboot Apache too: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Also, you won't lose ability to execute the Python script. The script just won't be able to do anything that requires super user privileges.